# Error C2664 cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'A &&' (compiles on VS2017 but not on VS2015)

Tags: c++, struct, initializer-list

I have an issue with this code. I can compile it when I use Visual Studio 2017 (v141) platform toolset. However, when I switch to Visual Studio 2015 (v140), I hit this error:

Error   C2664   'void std::vector<A,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const A &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'A &&'

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    double i;
    double j;
    int k = -1;
};
    
int main()
{
    std::vector<A> _object_rects;
    
    double i = 150;
    double j = 200;
    
    _object_rects.push_back({
        i,
        j });
    
    std::cout << "print structure: " << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << _object_rects[0].i << std::endl;
    std::cout << _object_rects[0].j << std::endl;
    std::cout << _object_rects[0].k << std::endl;
    
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: i assume that style initializer wasnt in the c++ version that vs2015 supports

Comment: Showed up in C++14 If I remember correctly. Not sure if VS2015 supports C++14 or if it defaults to C++11 and you need to request C++14.

Comment: I agree. The same is true for GCC: compiling with `--std=c++11` does not work while compiling with `--std=c++14` works.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your replies. I understand. What I find interesting is that when I don't define k in the struct (i.e. change "int k = -1;" to just "int k;"), I can compile just fine in both VS 2015 and VS 2017.

Comment: Yes, I think that has to do something with default constructors: by setting the default value for `k`, you overwrote the default constructor and thus initializers do not work anymore in C++11. C++14 is a little more flexible here. Feel free to upvote if that was helpful ;)